# How do I load a nib file from Code?

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I created a custom view in interface builder with a few buttons in it. I created a class in code for it as the "Files owner" to connect the buttons to action methods.

How do I use this class then?

I cannot just do it like this...

```
StartScreen *ss = [[StartScreen alloc] initWithFrame: ...];
[self.window.contentView addSubView: ss];
...
```

because this only produces an empty view. (of course: the StartScreen class doesn't know anything about the nib file yet.)

What I want to do is something like:

```
StartScreen *ss = LoadCustomViewFromNib(@"StartScreen");
[self.window.contentView addSubView: ss];
```

or maybe i have to say something like

```
[self iWannaBeANibWithName: @"StartScreen"];
```

in the constructor of StartScreen?

pls help...
(btw I am developing for Mac OS X 10.6)

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/iphone-how-to-load-a-view-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder)

Comment: I am not developing for iPhone.

Comment: it should work for Mac too like Dietrich has posted.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to make `StartScreen` a subclass of `NSViewController`, maybe changing its name to `StartScreenController`. This is a potentially more modular solution in case you have `IBActions` in your nib file and/or you want to place view controlling code in its own class.

1. Declare `StartScreenController` as a subclass of `NSViewController`
2. Declare `IBOutlets` in `StartScreenController` if needed
3. Set the nib file’s owner class to be `StartScreenController`
4. Connect the file’s owner `view` outlet to the view object, and other outlets if needed

Then:

```
StartScreenController *ss = [[StartScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibname" bundle:nil];    
[self.window.contentView addSubView:ss.view];
…
```

If you’re not using garbage collection, don’t forget to release `ss` when it’s not needed any longer.

Comment: well, this gives me an error: `-[NSViewController loadView] loaded the "StartScreen" nib but no view was set.` but I solved the problem finally: i directly initialize and instantiate a nib and traverse its top level objects to find the view object.

        NSNib *nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"StartScreen" bundle:nil];
     StartScreen *ss = [[StartScreen alloc] init];
     NSArray *aa;
     BOOL ok = [nib instantiateNibWithOwner: ss topLevelObjects: &aa];

aa contains two objects, and one is the view object that I need.

Comment: @Michael You’ve got that error because you’ve missed step 4: connect the `view` outlet.

Comment: thanks for the help! but I think this is more complicated than it should be. I solved it in a different way: I created my own view controller class (a subclass of NSObject) that does the nib loading stuff automatically. And it also connects the view to an instance variable. I just have to do `StartScreen *ss = [[StartScreen alloc] init];` and `[self.window.contentView addSubview: ss.view];` in the app delegate and everything works. There's not even the need to specify the nib name. -init just calls +nibName to get the nib name, and my default implementation just returns the class name.

Comment: @Michael You’ve essentially duplicated what `NSViewController` already does for you, so I’m not sure why using `NSViewController` is more complicated. Anyway, whatever works for you!

Answer (score 2):

The Nib loading functions are part of the `NSBundle` class.  You can use it like this...

```
@implementation StartScreen
- (id) init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        if (![NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"StartScreen" owner:self])
            // error
        // continue initializing
    }
    return self;
}
```

See [NSBundle Additions reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: It didn't work for me yet, but I think I identified the problem. I have made the StartScreen class a subclass of NSView. But I think it should be a subclass of NSObject, right? But how do I display this view then? I mean, I cannot just call [self.window.contentView addSubView:] in the app delegate, because I don't see a view object, do I?

Comment: (I suspect that it shouldn't be a subclass of NSView because you used -init as the constructor and not -initWithFrame:)

Comment: I now call the loadNibNamed: method in the -initWithFrame: constructor. I verified that it gets called and even the drawRect: method is called, but I don't see the contents of the nib-file on the screen.

Comment: In order to display a view, you must put it in a window.

Comment: I know :-) But where is the view? I didn't connect the view outlet as Bavarious pointed out. But finally, I don't like to do so much work just to display a nib file, so I created my own view controller class that Just Works (tm). Just needed 70 lines of code, including empty lines and comments, to create a view controller class that is actually better than NSViewController. With MyViewController I don't need to specify the nib name and I don't need to connect the view outlet.

Comment: Hm, it may "Just Work" with 70 lines of code, but using a Nib file it should be more like 4 lines of code, if not less.