# load view from a nib

Tags: iphone, nib

I've been struggling with this for a while and I think the solution is really simple, but I just can't get it right. I have a UIViewController, which has its view and now I would like to add a subview to it. Subview should be loaded from a nib. I've followed the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/iphone-how-to-load-a-view-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder), ie.:
 1. Create `MyView` class which is a subclass of UIView
 2. Declare IBOutlet properties in `MyView`
 3. Make .xib file, where File Owner is set to UIViewController and View class set to `MyView`
 4. Connect outlets
 5. In `MyViewController`, `viewDidLoad` method :

```
NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
MyView *mView;
for (id view in nibViews) {
   if ([view isKindOfClass:[MyView class]]) {
      mView = (MyView*) view;   
    }
}
[self.view addSubview:mView];
```

mView is loaded successfully, but when I try to add it as a subview I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I've even added:   `mView = [(MyView*) view retain];` but that doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure of your point 3:

Make .xib file, where File Owner is set to UIViewController and View class set to MyView

the file owner shouldn't be the uiviewcontroller, but the MyView class

Comment: You were right about that - I was following the steps in the referenced SO answer. Can't believe I didn't realize it sooner. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry...

You don't need to take separate nib file and referencing to the myView class again. Simply you can drag UIView from library into your current viewController's xib, and then u can simply connect the view from current view to the xib.

See below images:[image]

Comment: Now u can create in .h as: IBOutlet UIView *myView; and then add it when ever u want. Any queries , let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't want my view controller to have any knowledge of the IBOutlets from my view's .xib. I wanted my view subclass to own the IBOutlets. Unfortunately UIView doesn't have an `initWithNibName:` method, so I just created my own category.

Here's what I did:

- In IB, click on your main UIView, and in the Identity Inspector, set the class to your subclass
- In IB, click on File's Owner, and in the Identity Inspector, set the class to your subclass
- Use your new category method `initWithNibName:` to instantiate your view.

And here's the category I created:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName
{
    NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
    if (arrayOfViews.count < 1) {
        return nil;
    }

    self = arrayOfViews[0];

    return self;
}
```

Inspired by [this post](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2578-loading-a-nib-file-programmatically-objective-c/).

Note though, that so far the frame will adjust automatically, so unlike the code in the post, I haven't yet had to explicitly set the frame.
Also, unlike the post's code, I needed to set `owner:self` so the IBOutlets would be wired up correctly.