# Splitview app on Ipad

Tags: ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail, ipad

I'm the beginner on iOS development and iPad app programming. Now I'm working in an ipad splitview app in which I have multiple elements. In detail view of others view I added a UISegmentedControl and a UIView, what I want to do is when the Segmentedcontrol is switched the uiview should load and show another .nib file that i have in my project. My project is like this

---

Master --------------Detail

---

Picture   ----> Picture View

---

Video    ----> Video View.

---

Website  ---> Website View.

---

Others-------> Others View ((UIsegmentedControl))  ---> another .nib file

So how can i do that? Thank u!!!

Answer (score 0):

To receive action of your UISegmentedControl being clicked you need to do

```
    [mySegmentedControl addTarget: self action: @selector(mySegControlClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged] ;
```

Then implement your mySegControlClicked function like

```
    -(void)mySegControlClicked: (UISegmentedControl*)sender 
    {
           switch([sender selectedSegmentIndex]) {
                   case 0: //nib loading code ; 
                       break ;
                   case 1: //nib loading code ; 
                       break ;
            } 
    }
```

For help with the Nib loading code see [load view from a nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545962/load-view-from-a-nib)