# How to add a custom view to a XIB file defined view in monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to learn monotouch at the moment, and following the learn monotouch book by Mike BlueStein. Not a bad book, but it's slightly outdated since xcode 4 (i believe) and a newer version on monotouch has come out.

Anyways, in my project I have a controller and a xib file. I also have a custom view (e.g. myview : UIView), that overrides the draw method. I want to show my custom view next to or on top of the view defined in the xib file. How do I do this?

In the controller, If I override the LoadView method, and set the View to an instance of my custom view, then I can see it, but I loose everything defined in the xib file. If I try to add as a sub view, it does not appear at all.

What am I missing? If the question is not clear, please ask me, so I can clarify.

Cheers.

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/iphone-how-to-load-a-view-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder) might help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Follow the following steps to use a custom view in a XIB:

First, decorate the view with the `RegisterAttribute`:

```
[Register("MyView")]
public class MyView : UIView
{
}
```

and implement the following constructor:

```
public MyView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) {}
```

This constructor is needed for when the runtime will try to recreate the view after it has been destroyed by a memory warning. After you have created your custom class:

- Open the XIB in Xcode (always by double-clicking on it through MonoDevelop) and add a `UIView` where you want it.
- In Xcode, set that UIView's class to MyView (or whichever name you passed to the `RegisterAttribute`):

[image: Custom class for custom view]

- Compile-Run.

**EDIT:**

Do not override `LoadView` for controllers that are loaded from a XIB. `LoadView` is meant to create the controller's view when that controller's view is not loaded from a XIB.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Dimitris, great answer.

For those who get confused like me, here is the simplist procedure to add and use a Xib file as a partial / subview:

1. Add a new Xib File in MonoDevelop (ie `LoginView.xib`)
2. Add a new (partial) Class, this will be the custom class (The Code-behind file let 's say) for the view. Give it any name "`LoginView.cs`")
3. Add the Attribute (`RegisterAttribte`) and the `Constrctor` as exaplain above by 
   Dimitris.

   4. Double click the `LoginView.xib` to open it in XCode IB. Then Change the `Custom Class` Attribute of the xib file to point to your "code-behind file" (ie `LoginView.cs`)
4. Add any outlets or action if you need. MonoDevelop will generate a .designer file and attach it to your code-behind file, this is where you can see all your outlets and actions.
5. In your controllers where you want to add this view, load your .xib file as follows:

   var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("LoginView", this, null); 
   LoginView loginView = Runtime.GetNSObject(views.ValueAt(0)) as LoginView;
   mainLayout.AddSubview(loginView); 
   // where mainLoyout is the placeHolder in my main ViewController

These three lines are based on flexaddicted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188634/creating-a-custom-view-using-a-xib)