# How to create a UIView with Xib in MonoTouch

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to create a custom UITableViewCell with a XIB using MonoTouch/MonoDevelop.

When I choose File -> New -> File -> MonoTouch -> iPhone View, I get the Xib file but no associated UIView class.

I can create the view class separately, but then how do I get the associated designer.cs file and get it all wired up so that the integration between MonoDevelop and XCode works for setting up outlets and actions?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decorate your UITableViewCell class with the RegisterAttribute before opening the XIB in Xcode.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857558/how-to-add-a-custom-view-to-a-xib-file-defined-view-in-monotouch/9859690#9859690) answer.