# Interface Builder does not see my subclassed UILabel

Tags: xamarin.ios, interface-builder, uilabel, subclass

In MonoTouch I have defined the following class:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class WUILabel : UILabel
    {
        public WUILabel () : base() { this.SetDefaults(); }
        public WUILabel(NSCoder coder) : base(coder) { this.SetDefaults(); }
        public WUILabel(NSObjectFlag t) : base(t) { this.SetDefaults(); }
        public WUILabel(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { this.SetDefaults(); }
        public WUILabel(RectangleF frame) : base(frame) { this.SetDefaults(); }

        private void SetDefaults()
        {
            this.Font = UIFont.FromName("AmericanTypewriter", 15f);
            this.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

In Interface Builder, I am setting the "Class" attribute of my label to "WUILabel".

When I run the application, the Application Output contains the error "Unknown class WUILabel in Interface Builder file."  Has anyone successfully gotten this to work, or can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decorate your class with the RegisterAttribute.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857558/how-to-add-a-custom-view-to-a-xib-file-defined-view-in-monotouch/9859690#9859690) answer.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitris!  I had just figured it out and posted my answer when yours came through.

Comment: My class is decorated, yet I still get the error. This happens only when running on device, and I can see the error using xcode organizer console. In simulator everything is fine...

Comment: After restarting xamarin and cleaning the build, things got fixed