# How to link a ViewController in Xamarin MonoTouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm currently trialing MonoTouch and am impressed with it's capabilities thus far.

I'm wanting to create a library of iPhone apps that each will have the same User Logon screen. Therefore, I want to create the LogonScreen ViewController once and then share it amongst my projects.

I tried adding the files as a 'link' like you do with files in Visual studio but that seemed to create a disjoint between the Login.cs and the Login.designer.cs ie the Login.Designer.cs does not appear underneath the Login.cs in the Solution explorer.

The Login.cs has also lost the reference to the txtUsername textbox control I have in my xib.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly this will get you on track: [Dimitris Tavlikos Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857558/how-to-add-a-custom-view-to-a-xib-file-defined-view-in-monotouch?answertab=votes#tab-top)

This will produce a custom class which you can abstract into a common library for your applications.

-Nick

Answer (score 0):

Would advise you to add your shared views in a separated project (iOS Library Project) and add this project as a reference. 
You won't have the problems of linking separate files in each future project, which would get more and more complicated when you will have more shared views.

The reason why you lost the reference to your textfield is because it 'lost' the designer.cs file, which has these references.