# MonoTouch: add a custon view XIB

Tags: xamarin.ios, xib

I would like to add a custom view XIB to my UITable views header. Following this link [How to add a custom view to a XIB file defined view in monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857558/how-to-add-a-custom-view-to-a-xib-file-defined-view-in-monotouch/9859690#9859690)  i created a XIB with a view. It has just two labels in it.
I then have a cs file. Called XIB as mention in the link

```cs
public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, int sectionIndex) {


  var myHeader = new UIView(); 


  var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("CustomHeaderView", this, null); 
  CustomHeaderView loginView = Runtime.GetNSObject(views.ValueAt(0)) as CustomHeaderView;
  loginView.UpdateWithData("test","test");
  myHeader.AddSubview(loginView);
  return myHeader;
}
```

When i run the app it is crashing, dont see any error.

Comment: Please provide crash information from Application Output pad.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your .XIB is not using AutoLayout and you are using an older iOS.  The AutoLayout is new for 6.x and will cause a crash on the 5.x based devices.  I see this quite often.