# Replace "self" under ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, self

Usually my code with loading custom view from xib looks like:

```
@implemenation MyCustomView

- (id)init
{
    [self release];

    if ((self = [[NSBundle loadViewFromXibName:@"MyCustomView" withClass:[MyCustomView class] owner:nil] retain]))
    {
        //some init here
    }

    return self;
}
```

where `[NSBundle loadViewFromXibName:withClass:owner:]` - return atoreleased View, loaded from xib.

And all working properly.
But when I try write under ARC equivalent code:

```
@implemenation MyCustomView

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [NSBundle loadViewFromXibName:@"MyCustomView" withClass:[MyCustomView class] owner:nil]))
    {
        //some init here
    }

    return self;
}
```

my app crash with EX_BAD_ACCESS (release message sent to deallocated instance)
What happens in this case? And how can I solve this problem?

**UPDATED** This problem only on iOS6 SDK (iOS6 Simulator). On iOS5 SDK and iOS 5 Devices/Simulator all is fine.

**UPDATED** This problem appear only with table view cells, its deallocated in tableview lifecycle. I implemented static cell builder (what return cell loaded from xib) and moved internal cell initialization to awakeFromNib. Now all working properly.

I don`t understand why this problem should be - "self" is __strong and if I assign it any object it can`t be autoreleased. Is I mistaken?

Comment: loadViewFromXibName == ?

Comment: it`s a method from NSBundle category, load and return View (autoreleased) from xib.

Comment: The posted code is fine.

Comment: Traditionally , you would initialize `self` like this: `self = [super init]` which would NOT return an autoreleased object. Here , you return self as an autoreleased object , which is not supposed to happen from an `init` method . `[[Class alloc] init]` is supposed to return a retained object , and that is one of the ( seven , I think) rules that ARC respects.

Comment: Yes, I think so. But below ARC I can retain this object. Is where workaround with ARC?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/iphone-how-to-load-a-view-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder

Comment: @George: all of that doesn't matter. ARC handles all of that for you correctly. `init` is `ns_returns_retained`, thus the compiler ensures or converts whatever is assigned to `self` to `__strong` before returning.

Answer (score -1):

I used to do this pattern but after ARC I tried to avoid it by overriding `new` instead. I don't know why this causes problems but I'm guessing one of two things:

1. ARC handles the `[self release]` properly for you in the case of `self = [super init...]` because of the Cocoa `init` naming prefix. You won't get the same behavior if you load from nib (or somewhere else)
2. If you assign something to `self` that does not come from `[super init...]`, you lose the memory you allocated with `[MyCustomView alloc]`.

I'm inclined to think it's the latter. If you're loading from nib I suggest just do that in a factory method such as `new`, not from `init`.

Edit: When you said that this problem is on iOS 6 then I'm pretty sure you are encountering the same problem I had before. When I debugged this I even put a breakpoint inside `dealloc`. You'll see that it will stop there once every time you call `init`.

Comment: Yes, and it`s expected behavior. Empty object released and new loaded from xib.

Comment: "If you assign something to self that does not come from [super init...], you lose the memory you allocated with [MyCustomView alloc]." Of course you do. That's the point. We are trying to deallocate the original object and retain the object we get from the other method and return that

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead:

```
NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomClass" owner:nil options:nil];
self = [nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];
```

//ideally here it would be nice to loop through that array , check which view is member of your class and assign self to that.

in your init method.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: That's all the [NSBundle loadViewFromXibName:withClass:owner:] is doing