# UITableView with first section header fixed on top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am developing a table view where the header of the first section of a needs to be fixed at point.
I have set table view style as Plain. The section header is now fixed upto the point where the user scrolls in section 0. As soon as section 1 appears the header also scrolls up. Is there any way that the header of section 0 should always be fixed to the top?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can implement it as a fixed view, which is a sibling of your tableView if you don't want the header to be moved at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve so perhaps an edit is needed. However, it sounds like this isn't a good fit for UITableView. Messing with the scrolling mechanism of UITableView, if possible, would be very hard and introduce other challenges. Perhaps this is better done using tabs?

Comment: Yes i do not want it to be moved at all. So I have created a xib file for the header. How can i refer that and add as header to my table

Answer (score 0):

You should add `UIView` which looks like header and it will be at fix top position and after that view add tableview so when you scroll your `UIView` will not affected and remains at same position. So, you can manage your stuff like this!

Comment: Okay. But I have a xib for the view that i need as header. How can i access that in my view controller file

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/how-to-load-a-uiview-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/how-to-load-a-uiview-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder)

Comment: Thanks! But on doing this , my header is still scrolling... :(