# Can't figure out what am I doing wrong with loading custom view from .xib

Tags: ios, objective-c

in my [ViewController and Main storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqTJ1.png)
I'm trying to load a custom view (LogView) programmatically from .xib.
when the "Next" button is pressed a text supposed to appear in the custom sub view (myView). the "DidReceiveJSON" method suppose to load the custom view.
[This is how my LogView looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo74f.png) and the "Display" method suppose to update the "myLog" UIlabel.

EveryThing was working when "MyLog" view only contained a UIView and a UILabel. but I wanted to add a UIScrollView because the label grows every time "Next" button is pressed. 
So now when I press the "Next" button nothing is happening in the simulator.

could you please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

---

sorry for not uploading images, but I'm not allowed to upload any images due to my low rank. I did uploaded links to the images and will gladly add any info if needed

Comment: @ macmoonshine I can't add images because I'm a new user. but I added links to the images

Comment: @macmoonshine I tried to add images, but it didn't let me. said something about my rank being to low

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12568803/7064740
end up using this solution. thanks to @Francesco Vadicamo

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have connected outlet of MyLog UILabel with File's Owner in the xib. Check if the label is nil or not.

Comment: couldn't upload another link due to my low rank :(. here is the pic link https://s14.postimg.org/6631wqkqp/Screen_Shot_2016_12_03_at_2_53_13_PM.png

Comment: I putted a break point to see if myLabel gets assigned and everything is ok with it(not nil and it's content is the right one). but I don't really fully understand the file's owner part. who should be the owner? in my xib it's the viewController right now. I added a link to the xib file's owner part in the comment above