# iOS Swift how to show dynamic ui based on selction from drop list

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, dropdown

Heloo all,

I am new to ios swift. I have one problem in my screen.

I have one screen with drop down list of option like : `current bill,water bill., bike bill, loan bill, phone bill....so on`

I have sone this. But what i need is, whenever i select any option from drop down list. I need to show some ui elements like label, text filed, text box, lie that dynamically for each each selction in drop list.

For example :

if i select `water bill`, then below my drop down, i need to show the two label ui with name , id.

if i select `current bill` , then below my drop down , i need to show one text filed with place holder ' enter current bill number'

So like wise when ever i select any option from drop down..i need to show some dynamic ui.

How can i achive that ??

ANY HELP WILL BE USE FULL

Comment: Can't you just simply hide all those views and if you click specific option just make visible elements for it?

Comment: @Raymond  yes i too thought. But if i have 20 options in my drop down list..Then if i put 20 different ui  in same screen
??.... then will it the good practice / standard to show to user ?

Comment: Hmm, I see. Another solution. Make nib file for each option and display it after selecting one.

Comment: use container view

Comment: @Raymond   oaky if i create some currentbill.xib,waterbill.xib, like on..Then in same screen at below drop down list i will have one common view...But how can i call that xib files , when i select any option from drop list.Then how can i show that xib in my ui screen

Comment: @Maddy   container view?? can u explain it ..please

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1618147-loadnibnamed

Comment: @Raymond   thanks, but i am new to ios. If you give me some code example or github that will be help full for me to understand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/how-to-load-a-uiview-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder , if you do not understand obj c, you can always convert this code in objc to swift converter.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of container views to achieve that:

1- Add your drop down menu to any view controller you want.

2- Add a container view under that drop down menu and using auto layout make that container view fill the place that you want it to be switchable/dynamic.

3- Redo step 2 as many times as the items of the drop menu.

4- Create `IBOutlet`s for each of your container views and and an `IBAction` for your drop down menu.

5- In the `IBAction` of your drop down menu, set `isHidden` property of one container view to `false` and set it to `true` for the others based on the user's selection from the drop down menu.

Here is a [tutorial](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/) that explains that with a simple example.

Comment: okay, which means that, i need to place more container on same screen like one above one.....And i need to make ibaction of drop down list . and i need to use some bool thing to show the container view based on my drop down selection..Right ??

Comment: But its look like same think that we are doing like placing the uiview in same screen as one above right ?.. SO does it is the good practive to keep more container one by one above ??

Comment: Yes, you'll have many container views above each other, and you'll control which one is visible from your drop down menu's `IBAction` based on the user's selection.
Having many container views is not an issue, each container view will have a view controller embedded in it, so you'll manage everything related to each container view's view controller in a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop `viewcontrollers` in your storyboard for your current `bill,water bill., bike bill, loan bill, phone bill`etc.

And when ever you change the option from your drop down list use below code to add your required controller as child controller.

```
let currentBill  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "currentBill") as! CurrentBillVC

// remove other views           
for k in 0..<self.parentView.subviews.count {
    self.parentView.subviews[k].removeFromSuperview()

}

self .addChildViewController(currentBill)

// Add view to your maincontroller i named it parent view in which you want to display other controller w.r.t your drop down list.

self.parentView .addSubview(currentBill.view) 

currentBill.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```