# How to load a custom XIB view written in swift programatically in an Objective-C Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have created a XIB for UIView named popUpView.xib and a swift file associated with it popUpView.swift

My popUpView.swift code is like this:

```
@objc class popUpView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mobileNumberTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var customerIdTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var panNumberTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveBtn: UIButton!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.initSubViews()
    }        
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.initSubViews()
    }
    
    func initSubViews() {
        
        let name = String(describing: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: name, bundle: .main)
        nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
        
        self.addSubview(self.containerView)
        self.containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addConstraints()
    }
    
    func addConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to load this view as a popUp in my ViewController written in Objective-C

In my ViewController, I am calling like this:

```
-(void)showPopUpView {
    
         popUpView *popUpView = [[popUpView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [self.view addSubview:popUpView];
        [popUpView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor constant:25].active = YES;
        [popUpView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor constant:25].active = YES;
        [popUpView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor constant:25].active = YES;
        [popUpView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor constant:25].active = YES;    
}
```

In viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self showPopUpView];
}

I think I might be doing it the wrong way. What is the right way to load this custom view programatically in Obj-C?
```

Comment: I think you are missing the constraints for the popup view in ViewController. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @Arun I have added the constraints, still view doesn't show up. I am calling it from viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: Maybe add translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false for the popup view

Comment: This will help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863321/how-to-load-a-uiview-using-a-nib-file-created-with-interface-builder

Comment: @Arun I was not able to load the view programatically. But now after I took a view in myViewController XIB and giving the view class as popUPView, I am able to show. This is not actually what I wanted but Its working fine for now.. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Please refer my answer

Answer (score 0):

I got curious since the last time I did this, so I created a project to test it out. This is how it works for me.

My xib:
[image]

My PopupView.m
[image]

My ViewController.m
[image]

Added the code to this GitHub repo:
https://github.com/ArunEA/ObjcViewWithNib